# Subgraph Centrality - Optimization

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I'm implementing some calculations on networks, and one of the properties I'm using is the Subgraph Centrality (developed on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0504730.pdf)). The equation I'm using is the equation (4) on the paper.

I wrote the following code for the equation:

```
eigenvalues = Chop[Eigenvalues[N[Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[graph]]]]];
eigenvectors= Eigenvectors[N[Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[graph]]]];
subCentrality=Table[N[Sum[(Power[eigenvectors[[i,j]],2])*Exp[eigenvalues[[i]]], {i,VertexCount[graph]}]],{j,Length[eigenvectors]}];
```

Where 'graph' is any graph. The data I'm using is on [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1srvP-UYfKgfRqpFlykR5ZaFoXm7RXd3c), which corresponds to the 'AdjacencyMatrix' of my network. Using this formula, it took me about 9h to complete the calculation. That could be a suitable time if I had to calculate it only once, but I'm trying to implement it in some algorithms, where I'll have to calculate this about 2000-3000 times.
Is there a way of optimizing this code?

Comment: You might use EigenSystem to get both the values and vectors at once -- with luck this might cut the time in half.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should save you several hours...

```
{λ, U} = Eigensystem[N[Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[graph]]]];
subCentrality2 = Exp[λ].(U U);
```

Note that the exponential might be problematic as it easily kicks you out of the machine numbers. (When that happens, the matrix-vector product slows
down considerably.)